# Convert Web App to Dapp for Blockchain Implementation

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, daap

I have my web-application which is in Angular2(Front end) and Rails(back end- API), now I want to implement Blckchain to this application, so needs to make it Dapp.

Here while making the Dapp, do I need to remove the Rails Back-end and convert the business login into the smart-contracts(Ethereum)?

Do I need to require to choose the cloud storage platform like Storj, Decent for storing the data?

Please share any online material/blogs which can help me into this.

EDIT

This application is having more than 50 API's, so should I have to write the 50+ smart contract for each API? that means I need to remove the all Rails API code.

Answer (score 1):

Ethereum Smart contracts don't have logins…

Here is one of the best resources I can give you: 
what you want to do first is to understand how the smart contracts work from here:

https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-smart-contract-development-with-a-web-app-part-1-develop-the-smart-contract-ee2a7c735936

then you need to understand how to store data on the Ethereum blockchain:

https://medium.com/@ConsenSys/an-introduction-to-ipfs-9bba4860abd0

Then last you can learn more about the DApps:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Decentralized-apps-(dapps)

https://www.udemy.com/ethereum-dapp/